# Android: Base Adapter Weird Null Pointer

Tags: android

Sorry for the title but its an issue that i cannot seem to summarise

So i made a class that extends the AutoCompleteTextView

I made a base adapter class that implements the Filterable interface

I set this adapter

I get a null pointer when getCount is called which states that the array list is null. This is where things get weird

This is my base adapter constructor

```
public PieceSearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> food) {
    mContext = context;
    mFoods = new ArrayList<>();
    mFoods.addAll(food);
}
```

The above is what i have after i diagnosed the issue

So its impossible for the array list to be null now

```
  @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFoods.size();
    }
```

The null pointer still occurs

So i debugged at the point in the base adapter constructor. The items passed in are NOT null and contain the items.

I am not sure what the issue is.

Stack trace:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
            at REDACTED.FoodSearchAdapter.getCount(PieceSearchAdapter.java:36)
            at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView$PopupDataSetObserver$1.run(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1291)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Tried Karan Mer solution**

```
private List<Food> mFoods;

public PieceSearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> food) {
    mContext = context;
    mFoods =  new ArrayList<Food>(food);
}
```

Same problem

**Checking the size of the mFoods array in constructor**

```
 public PieceSearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> food) {
        mContext = context;
        mFoods = new ArrayList<>(food);
        if(mFoods == null){
            DebugUtils.Log("Yes its null");
        }
        else{
            DebugUtils.Log("Not null, its size is " + mFoods.size());
        }
    }
```

Output was

```
Not null, its size is 11
```

**Rohan Solution**

Not a try catch but its the same thing

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(mPieces != null){
        return mPieces.size();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Does not crash, but i get the following exception when changing the text of my AutoCompleteTextView to run a filter operation.

```
344-962/W/Filter﹕ An exception occured during performFiltering()!
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at REDACTED.FoodSearchAdapter$FoodFilter.performFiltering(FoodSearchAdapter.java:108)
            at android.widget.Filter$RequestHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

This is the line 108. Where the for starts

```
for (Food food : mFood) {
                    if (food.getReferenceNumber().matches("(?i:.*" + constraint + ".*)") || piece.getName().matches("(?i:.*" + constraint + ".*)")) {
                        filteredFoods.add(food);
                    }
                }
```

Basically the member mFoods is null again :(

**My entire filter logic**

```
private class FoodFilter extends Filter {

        /**
         * Filter the data based on a pattern in a worker thread
         *
         * @return FilterResults: Contains two members, a count indicating the amount of results and the data itself
         */
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            //Do we have any constraints passed in?
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(constraint)) {
                ArrayList<Food> filteredFood = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Food food : mFood) {
                    if (food.getReferenceNumber().matches("(?i:.*" + constraint + ".*)") || food.getName().matches("(?i:.*" + constraint + ".*)")) {
                        filteredFood.add(food);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filteredFood.size();
                results.values = filtered;
            }
            return results;
        }
```

And this is the publishResults method

```
 @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            if (filterResults != null) {
                mFood = (ArrayList<Food>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
```

**More weird. An array adapter works for me but not a base adapter**

```
ArrayAdapter<Food> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, Food);
```

And in my toString method of the Food model

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return mName;
}
```

So there is something wrong with base adapter but im not sure. At least this proves that the data i am supplying is good otherwise this would not work.

Comment: instead of copying values and then adding them try using `List<Food> this.mFoods = new ArrayList<Food>(oldList);`

Comment: Try `mFoods = new ArrayList<Food>();`

Comment: @KaranMer please check my edit. I tried the solution but i get the same problem

Comment: what is line 36 PieceSearchAdapter.java:36

Comment: post the whole adapter class code if possible

Comment: @KaranMer Line 36 is the get count method which is posted above. At the point of the return mFoods.size()

Comment: add try catch surrond mFoods.size() and in catch return 0;

Comment: check what is the size of food list in constructor

Comment: Try declaring "List<Food> mFoods;" as a global variable in the adapter, and then just set the values with "this.mFoods = food" in the constructor

Comment: @KaranMer posted log statement of size.

Comment: @RohanPawar trying now

Comment: May be getCount() is getting called even before array is initialized! I am not sure about it. Have u logged the count in getCount() before returning?

Comment: your ListView or other AdapterView-derived type is trying to use the adapter before you've initialized it with it's data.

Comment: @RohanPawar tried the solution. Check edit, does not crash but my filtering does not work because it says the member array is null again

Comment: i think basic problem is in your filter logic

Comment: If you're trying to have a Filter in the adapter, you need to use 2 lists in the adapter. For example: private ArrayList<Food> items; private ArrayList<Food> filteredItems = new ArrayList<>(); and in constructor: PieceSearchAdapter(ArrayList<Food> items...) this.items = items; this.filteredItems.addAll(items); Also, you need to use filteredItems for the getCount() and getItem()...

Comment: @BojanIlievski I will post more code. I have this.

Comment: @BojanIlievski posted the code. Please see edit

Comment: I am pretty much following this tutorial. Looking at the base adapter implementation http://codetheory.in/android-filters/

Comment: Try something like this: http://pastebin.com/DBfTXM9V (the previous one was faulty)

Comment: @BojanIlievski  I am confused with the code. The filterString is not used. The list is equal member "item" reference . The food object outside the for loop is not needed. Plus the "list" collection would be null since its reference points to member "items" The problem i am having is the member array list is null

Comment: Again... my bad, I'm adjusting a working solution to your code, and I forgot the filterString... So, here's the final version: http://pastebin.com/2vCXG6Vc

Comment: It's a code that I use in my adapters. It's tested and it works. This is the remaining code for the constructor and the global lists: http://pastebin.com/UDGSVBPX

Just try it out as provided...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87884/discussion-between-bojan-ilievski-and-john-carter).

Comment: @BojanIlievski, i tried the code exactly how it is. I still get the original problem

Comment: Posted another update. Getting more weird :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue.

I had a number of problems that Bojan llievski and Rohan Pawar pointed out

The key issue was here

```
 @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            if (filterResults != null) {
                mFood = (ArrayList<Food>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
```

So FilterResults  is never null but the values member can be null so here i was setting my mFood member to null when no results were found. And since i did not set a threshold, no characters would instantly make my member array list null hense the null pointer.

The solution is to create another array list like this

```
 private ArrayList<Food> mOriginalFoodPieces;
    private ArrayList<Food> mFilteredPiecesToShow = new ArrayList<>();

    private final Context mContext;

    public PieceSearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Food> food) {
        mContext = context;
        mOriginalFood = food;
    }
```

So all other methods like getCount and getView will use the mFilteredPiecesToShow array list. Do not touch the mOriginalFood array list as we need to preserve the data set for filtering.

And the publishResults method looks like this

```
@Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            DebugUtils.Log("publishResults called");
                Object filterResult = filterResults.values;
                if(filterResult != null){
                    mFilteredFoodToShow = (ArrayList<Food>) filterResult;
                }
                else{
                    mFilteredFoodToShow.clear();
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```